# Docker Dynamodb Error: Nodejs App with dynamodb does not work in docker but works without it

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I made a simple nodejs app with only one table in dynamodb. I am using [Vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) as the datawrapper. ***It works very well if I do not dockerize it.***

I tried running the docker exactly the way I run the app in development mode too. That too did not work.

Here is the code I use to create tables:

```
module.exports = function () {
    const vogels = require('vogels');
    // const AWS= require('aws-sdk');
    const Lr = require("../api/models/LRModel");
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
        AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: "myKeyId", secretAccessKey: "secretKey", region: "us-west-2" });
        vogels.dynamoDriver(new AWS.DynamoDB({ endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000' }));
    } else {
        console.log("AWS access key=", process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, "AWS Secret key=", process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY, "AWS Region =", process.env.AWS_REGION);
        vogels.AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY, region: process.env.AWS_REGION, sslEnabled: false });

    }

    vogels.createTables({
        'lrs': {readCapacity: 10, writeCapacity: 10}
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error creating tables: ', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Tables have been created');
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the error I get in docker:

```
server-0   | Error creating tables:  { TimeoutError: Missing credentials in config
server-0   |     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/vogels/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:61:34)
server-0   |     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
server-0   |     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
server-0   |     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:7)
server-0   |     at Socket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:626:10)
server-0   |     at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
server-0   |     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
server-0   |     at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
server-0   |     at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:339:8)
server-0   |     at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
server-0   |   message: 'Missing credentials in config',
server-0   |   code: 'CredentialsError',
server-0   |   time: 2017-06-29T05:36:23.724Z,
server-0   |   originalError:
server-0   |    { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
server-0   |      code: 'CredentialsError',
server-0   |      time: 2017-06-29T05:36:23.724Z,
server-0   |      originalError:
server-0   |       { message: 'Missing credentials in config',
server-0   |         code: 'CredentialsError',
server-0   |         time: 2017-06-29T05:36:23.721Z,
server-0   |         originalError: [Object] } } }
```

One thing I clearly notice when I run it ***WITHOUT*** docker is that the dynamodb end point is a **http** end point. Here is the endpoint logged from https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/8904e9c730fb2fccf9d201f66266a6e2cbb75348/lib/http/node.js
(line number 13).

```
server-0   |   Endpoint {
server-0   |   protocol: 'https:',
server-0   |   host: 'dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com',
server-0   |   port: 443,
server-0   |   hostname: 'dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com',
server-0   |   pathname: '/',
server-0   |   path: '/',
server-0   |   href: 'https://dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/',
server-0   |   constructor: { [Function: Endpoint] __super__: [Function: Object] } }
```

When I run it ***WITH*** docker is that the dynamodb end point is a **httpS** end point. Here is the endpoint logged from https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/8904e9c730fb2fccf9d201f66266a6e2cbb75348/lib/http/node.js
(line number 13).

```
server-0   |   Endpoint {
server-0   |   protocol: 'http:',
server-0   |   host: '169.254.169.254',
server-0   |   port: 80,
server-0   |   hostname: '169.254.169.254',
server-0   |   pathname: '/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/',
server-0   |   path: '/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/',
server-0   |   href: 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/' }
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the app without using docker the credentials are being extracted from `/.aws/credentials`. I was under the impressions that it is happening through `vogels.AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY, region: process.env.AWS_REGION, sslEnabled: false });`

I logged the options in update function in config.js of `aws-sdk` and found this with the help of the input of a friend.

The culprit seems to be that the table definition should be after up config is updated.
I brought this line `const Lr = require("../api/models/LRModel");`
below config.update and it is working well now